# D3 Zoom Jitters

Tags: d3.js

D3 drag jitters when I `.call(zoom)` on two overlapping elements - and try to drag on the top element.

Here is an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbNjqg

In this case, zoom has been registered on the chart's bars and on the chart's background.

I can't add an invisible rectangle over the entire chart to register the zoom because that element would prevent mouseovers from registering on individual bars.

Why does this shaky horizontal scrolling occur - and how can I fix it?

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988445/d3-behavior-zoom-jitters-shakes-jumps-and-bounces-when-dragging?rq=1

Comment: That is the same problem, but their solution does not work in this case.  I can't put a no-fill 'g' over the entire chart to register zoom because I still want to register mouseover events on individual bars of the chart.