# Strange D3 pan/zoom behaviour - accelerating pan

Tags: d3.js, zooming, panning

I have got a d3 example where panning on the x axis results in accelerated panning. That is, when I hold the left button down and move the pointer, the data pans in a non-linear way. This is probably best illustrated in an example, see:

https://bl.ocks.org/sachams/d8621093ebb8181d50fe

I read some posts which suggested the problem is that I had attached the zoomer to the same element I was capturing mouse input with, and that I had to place an extra  between them ([d3.behavior.zoom jitters, shakes, jumps, and bounces when dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988445/d3-behavior-zoom-jitters-shakes-jumps-and-bounces-when-dragging)).

I have tried all sorts of combinations of adding different child elements and attaching my zoomer to different places, but can't find one that works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you're resetting the x domain for the zoom behaviour in your zoom handler. You shouldn't need to do that, as you've already "attached" the x scale to the zoom behaviour.

Comment: That was it - thanks!! I made the zoom handler call the following function and that fixed it:

`function updateZoom(){
        xAxisG.call(xAxis);
        yAxisG.call(yAxis);

        xGridG.call(xGrid);
        yGridG.call(yGrid);

        // Add the line
        path.datum(scope.data).attr('d', line);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your zom handler function (`update()`) you're resetting the domain of the x scale:

```
x.domain(scope.range);
// ...
Zoomer.x(x) // update the zooming behavior to match the domain
```

The first line is what causes the jittering. Before calling this code, you've set `scope.range` to `x.domain()` in the function called directly by the zoom behaviour, so this is unnecessary. The second line isn't necessary either as you've already told the zoom behaviour to "track" the `x` scale, but doesn't do any harm in this case.